# Calculation looping through dataframe of lists and list of arrays

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, loops, euclidean-distance

I want to calculate the Euclidean distance using a list of arrays.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.spatial import distance

#Dataframe
data = [np.array([[1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 1]]),
        np.array([[1, 2, 3], [3, 1, 2], [3, 2, 1]])]
names = ['A', 'B']

df = pd.DataFrame(dict((k,list(v)) for k,v in zip(names, data)))
df

#List of arrays
num = [np.array([-1, 2]), np.array([3,  2, -1])]
num
```

What I'm trying to do is loop through and calculate the Euclidean distance between each row in the first column of the dataframe and the first array in list `num`, each row in the second column with second array and so on.

So far I've tried:

```
columns=list(df)
for column in columns:
    data = np.array(list(df[column]))
    for row in data:
        distance.euclidean(row, num)
```

Which gives the error:

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,) (3,)
```

My desired output is the distance:

[image]

In my real dataset, there are over a 1000 columns and list of arrays, so I want to avoid hard coding any column name/index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an empty df named `result_df`. Then iterate over columns and arrays.
After calculating distances(`results`) for that column, assign it to specific column using `result_df[column] = pd.Series(results)`:

```
result_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=df.columns)
for idx, column in enumerate(df):
    results = []
    for arr in df[column].values:
        results.append(distance.euclidean(arr,num[idx]))
    result_df[column] = pd.Series(results)
# Print Distances
result_df
```

Outputs as:

[image]